# cannot able to set httponly cookie for https connection in express-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I am trying to set the httpOnly cookie from the backend using express-session along with passport. But the set-Cookie header is not being set in the response headers. No information why it is not being set.

**Server - Node**

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "newsecret@123",
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        maxAge: 31 * 24 * 3600000,
    },
    store: new redisStore({client: client}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require("./config/passport.js")(passport, models.User);

router.post(
    "/login",
    passport.authenticate("local-signin"),
    async (req, res) => {
            await req.session.save();
}
```

**Client - React**

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: "https://backend.new_secret.com/",
});

await api.post("user/login", data)
```

For localhost i have already setup the ssl certs and enabled https connection.
The Set-Cookie Header is not being set in the response header as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtJ5l.png).

when tried without sameSite: "none" or with SameSite:false the browser flagged that set-Cookie cant be set as sameSite should be none. when tried with secure false the browser flagged that secure should be true when using sameSite as none. With secure false and no samesite it works in postman but not in react browser.

I need the response header to set the browser cookie.